# Get file list from SQL table, display in PHP and check if files are live

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to get some data from my SQL table , im using the code below for this

```
<?php   
 $connect = mysqli_connect("SERVER", "USER", "PASS", "DATABASE");  
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM firmware ORDER BY ID DESC";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
 ?>
```

This is then placed into a PHP table like so

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
echo "<tr><td>" . $row[idFirmware] . "</td><td>" . $row['URL'] . "</td></tr>";}

echo "</table>"; 
mysql_close();
```

This all works fine, however id like the PHP table to also show if the file is live or not. As an individual file, the below works fine (but is very slow), however I don't want to have to manually inpuit this code for every single line in the table

```
if(file_get_contents('www.example.com/file.txt)) {
    //File exists
    echo 'Alive';
}
```

Is there a way I can have the table auto generate the file list (using the previous SQL query) then as a separate Colum in the table, have it check if the file is live or not?

As an added complexity, there are 2 or more URL's per row, separated by a , so "http://example.com/file.txt,http://example2.com/file.txt" It would need to check both and show the status of both, but this can be done on the same line. The servers are different (for redundancy) but the file name and location are the same

I can write something that does one thing, or the other, but cannot figure out how to combine them!

Comment: "This all works fine ..." - Interesting. How can that work, when you mix `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` functions?

Comment: Sorry, I was copying the non mysqli sections from code that wasn't mine to save sanitising my code, but for the sake of example, theyre the same anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the confusion pointed out between `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions is a typo.

If that's the case just run all of your checks on the same loop

PHP

```php
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

echo "<table>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {   //Creates a loop to loop through results
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['idFirmware'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['URL'] . "</td>";

    // Check your files here
    echo "<td>";
    foreach (explode(',', $row['URL']) as $file_url) {
        // Use file exists to avoid loading file data if you're only checking if it's there
        echo file_exists($file_url) ? 'Live' : 'Not Live';
    }
    echo "<td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($connect);
```

The slowness you're experiencing is likely due to having to download the file via `file_get_contents` or simply connection delay.

Comment: That seems to mostly work and yes as mentioned, it does pull down the data into a nice table but every link shows "Not Live", yet if you copy and paste them out of the table, the file downloads correctly.

I would suspect something is going wrong in the explode command at a guess, so its sees each URL as one? but im not sure on this.

Appreciate your speeds response however that seems 99% of the way correct!

That way of checking is indeed MUCH faster, i dont care about loading the file, i just need to know at a quick glance if one of the 900+ files is dead so i can replace it!